# arcpy.mapping exportPDF with ONLY one buffer ring turned on for associated iterated feature

Tags: arcpy, buffer, python-script-tool

I am exporting X number of maps iterating through a point feature class. Each feature class has a buffer drawn around them. I know how to export a PDF for each feature class at a fixed scale (if I lock extent the map just pans from one feature to another and works; however, if I don't lock the extent and write zoomtofeature code then the map never refreshes and I get the same extent for every iterated feature). I can get by that for now although it is frustrating.

How can I export a PDF for each feature but with only the associated buffer ring turned on and all others turned off? (many buffer rings overlap each other and I've been asked to produce just one ring per feature regardless of overlapping buffers from nearby features).

Comment: In definition query go to data driven pAGES

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are looping through the geometry and panning around via a Search Cursor, you can set a [definition query on a layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Layer/00s300000008000000/) to show **only** the Buffer that has the OID equal the the feature you are currently on as you step through the table.  Make sure you call `arcpy.RefreshActiveView()` **before** exporting to PDF.

For example:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr, ['OID@']) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        lyr.definitionQuery = "OBJECTID = {}".format(row[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm still stuck with this. Here's my exact script with some #comments to help myself understand exactly what's occurring or where I'm going wrong: